# Avoid fire on a battery-powered device

Tags: batteries, battery-operated, short-circuit, troubleshooting, water

I was trying to repair a battery-powered electric razor when I suspect there was a short-circuit.

The device started heating and it began smoking a bit so I took it and put it in a bowl full of water.

I guess this wasn't the best idea but now I'm stuck with the device still working, sunk into water as on the picture and I have no idea what to do. I know it may not be the best place to ask but I'm really stressed right now.

The device has a non-removable 5V / 5W battery.

I would appreciate any help on what to do.

[image: picture]

Comment: Any battery is removable if you try hard enough.

Comment: Now it's in the water I am a bit scared of touching it. Any clue what will happen if I remove the device from the water? Should I wait for the battery to empty itself?

Comment: Put it into a steel cooking pot with a heavy lid. Put on safety glasses when opening it.

Comment: Waiting for it to drain its battery on its own sounds like a sound course of action. Like Transistor said, putting it in some kind of container would be a good idea, just in case something goes wrong. It shouldn't do much more than heat up, but it's a good idea to be safe when dealing with lithium batteries.

Comment: I did put it inside a cooking pot with a heavy lid, but didn't remove it from the water/bowl. I put it outside on my balcony and pray for it not to catch fire. Thanks for your help. I hope I did well

Comment: Even if it does catch fire, it's outside, in a cooking pot with a heavy lid.  The worst case is that you need to thoroughly clean the burnt remains from the pot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The device has a non-removable 5V / 5W battery.

The device may be *charged* with 5V / 5W power supply, but the battery is most likely a 3.7V Lithium-Polymer type.

> The device started heating and it began smoking a bit so I took it and
>   put it in a bowl full of water.
>
> I guess this wasn't the best idea

If the Lithium-Polymer battery was heating and smoking then this probably *was* the best idea. When a Lipo battery is shorted out it can heat up enough to go into [thermal runaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_runaway), causing it to catch fire and explode. Immersing the battery in water cools it down enough to prevent thermal runaway (even when it is smoking profusely and has flames shooting out of it - ask me how I know!).

Since your device is still working that suggests the short has gone, so you could remove it from the bowl, *disconnect the battery*, and dry the device out thoroughly. You should then disassemble it and clean off any corrosion which may have occurred due to [electrolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis) while it was under water.

If the battery is damaged in any way (cuts, burn marks, 'puffy' or has a 'chemical' smell) then put it back in the bowl of water and leave it there until the voltage drops below 2V. You can then safely dispose it in the trash.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, this is reassuring. Curious why it becomes safe to trash the battery when the voltage goes below 2V.

Comment: Below 2V it has practically no capacity left, so even if punctured or shorted out it shouldn't have enough energy to catch fire. It may take several weeks for the battery to completely discharge in fresh water, so salt can be added to increase conductivity. If you are still worried about the little capacity remaining then drive a nail though the cell - in a well ventilated area in case it smokes.Note that discharging the battery through its leads will **not** work if it has an internal over-discharge protection circuit! (they typically cut off at 2.5V).

Comment: Just so you know, I followed your advice. All good, no fire. Just a puffy battery I'll recycle! Thanks a bunch. I'll delete this question in 24h as it is slightly off topic.